# Sign Up to Amazon Web Service Cognito Error InvalidParameterException

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito

I am trying to sign users up by phone number using Amazon Web Services (Cognito) but i got this error object:

> Object {   "code": "InvalidParameterException",   "message": "Username
>   should be a phone number.",   "name": "InvalidParameterException", }

here is my sign up function:

```
  signUp = () =>{
  const {username,email,password,phone_number} = this.state;
  Auth.signUp({
    username,
    password,
    attributes:{
      email,
      phone_number,
    }
  }).then(()=>{
    //navigate to confirming phone number screen
    this.props.navigation.navigate('ConfirmPhoneNumber',phone_number);
  })
  .catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

and here is my user pool attributes:
[image: User-pool attributes]

then i changed the username attribute by passing phone number to it instead of username as the following:

```
username:phone_number,
```

that made the sign up work but when i checked the new user in the userpool
the user name was like this (`93325cc2-27d0-47f6-a5b6-1ce73bcc157e`)
the problem is: how do i add username instead of this generated one ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The country code has to be present

`Phone numbers must follow these formatting rules: A phone number must start with a plus (+) sign, followed immediately by the country code. A phone number can only contain the + sign and digits. You must remove any other characters from a phone number, such as parentheses, spaces, or dashes (-) before submitting the value to the service. For example, a United States-based phone number must follow this format: +14325551212.`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html